# Touch Bar to only showing my customized layout at all times

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

How do I configure the Touch Bar on the new Macbook Pro's to only show my customized layout at all times?  Forgive for the question if I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In System Preferences/Keyboard, you just set the "Touch Bar Shows" drop-down in the Keyboard tab to "Expanded Control Strip", and use the Customize Control Strip button to set up that expanded control strip however you want.

Comment: Good catch! Not sure if "expanded control strip" is what he means by "customized layout" but it's a solid guess

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're referring to a customized view you made on one app applying to all your apps. If not, skip this section.

The touch bar is configured separately for every view you are in within each app (so there are multiple configurations within the same app such as composing and reading mail or example) but there are also system settings for the 4 icons that always show up on the right of the touch bar and the icons that show up when you click the arrow next to those. These can be customized in Settings -> Keyboard -> Customize Control Strip.

So you can't choose one layout to display at all times, for example somebody asked if they [could add emoji to touch bar globally](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277877/can-i-add-emojis-to-touch-bar-globally) and I explained you cannot.

--

If asking about the "Expanded Control Strip":

- Settings -> Keyboard and set it so "Press <kbd>fn</kbd> key to" - "Expand Control Strip". Helpful trick!
- "Touch Bar Shows" > "Expanded Control Strip" (kudos to @mike-scott for reminding me)